# How to get Current State of checkbox in thymeleaf th:onclick?

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

I have a Checkbox and I call a function with th:onclick. This function takes the Value of checkbox After I Click it. But I don't Know How to Get the State of Checkbox Inside of th:onclick. the code looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" th:onclick="'javascript:userSettings(' + ${user.id} + ', this );'" th:checked="${user.enabled}" />
```

my function:

```
function userSettings(userId,userChk) { alert(userChk)}
```

After Clicking the Checkbox, the Value of "userChk" is undefiend.

How Can I Fix That?

Comment: for example after clicking the checkbox, the value of checked is false. I need to pass this "false" to my function.

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: Yes I am using jquery. but for now i just want to get the value of "userChk".

Answer (score 1):

My Fault, I forgot to get the Value of It:

```
function userSettings(userId,userChk) { alert(userChk.checked)}
```